# How to convert yyMMDDHHMMSS to a valid date using pandas function to_datetime() without providing format?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

So I'm new to python and pandas. I'm using `to_datetime` function to convert 1605121950805 into a real date format. If I use:

```
dates=pd.to_datetime(1605121950805, infer_datetime_format=True,yearfirst=True)
```

I get: `1970-01-01 00:26:45.121950805`

If I use format parameter it works fine:

```
dates=pd.to_datetime(1605121950805, format='%y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
```

Output: `2016-05-12 19:50:08.050000`

So if I specifying a format it works but I would like to know is there any way to make it work without format parameter, so `infer_datetime_format` can guess the right format?

Comment: Have you tried converting 1605121950805 (which is an integer) to string?

Comment: Whats wrong with passing a format?  The `1605121950805` can be ambiguously parsed into many different dates.  How is `to_datetime` supposed to choose which one you meant?  You need to give it some help.  Now if you used something less ambiguous, it can infer.  But infer isn't a synonym for mind read.

Comment: @Błotosmętek yes I did and I get an error with this: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long.

Comment: @piRSquared There is nothing wrong, but I'm trying to make like a smart parser which can extract that date from file, and if I give him format I'm not sure is that smart enough. I thought that maybe I was doing something wrong.That is why I try to find other way around, if not I will use it with format. Any suggestion for other method?